# Apply Catalog Price Rule Excluding Tax

Tags: magento2.4.5

I Created New catalog price rule in 2.4.5.

Product A = Price = 103  [ 100 + 3 ]

Where 100 is Product Price  & 3 is Tax.

After I created Catalog Price rule, Now the discount is applying to 103, but i want to apply discount for only 100.

I do not want to apply discount for TAX  [ 3 ].

or Can we do this with Shopping Cart Price Rule ?

**update**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change `Apply Discount On Prices` configuration in `Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings` to `Excluding Tax`

[image: Apply Discount On Prices Configuration]

Comment: i have updated screenshot of backend configuration, it set to  "excluding tax" only

Comment: wait, we are displaying price in backend including tax, previous developers done like that,  so discount should apply for (price - [3 % of price ] )

Comment: Yeah i guess you need to update the other tax related configurations based on your country, please refer to this documentation (https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/stores-sales/site-store/taxes/international-tax-guidelines.html)

Comment: i misunderstood the logic as this project done by previous developers. here is a new [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/370234/apply-catalog-price-rule-on-97-price-of-the-total-product-price)

Comment: @BabyinMagento I have responded to you on the other question; let's get it resolved.

Comment: i m  checking nowe