# apply catalog price rule on 97 % price of the total product price

Tags: catalog-price-rules, magento2.4.5

in backend , for Product A we set the price = 100.

We created catalog price rule with 20 % for all products.

the catalog price rule should not apply for full price.

it should apply for ( product price - 3% of product price )

ex : (100 - 3) or 97 % of product price.

Means for only 97, the 20 % discount should apply.

If the product price is 1000, than only for 970 - the catalog price should apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be dumb idea but have you considered changing your tax rate ? Cause to simplify calculation lets say original price is 100 you want 20% tax...but not on 100 but on 50...well then it should be the same as 10% of 100

So in your case it would be like applying 19.4% rate ?

Comment: please help my friends [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to switch `Apply Tax On` to `Original price only` in the Tax configuration?

[image]

Comment: the original price itself is 100 , this did not work for me , sorry. here is [link](https://frontend1.staging.glowjewels.com/floral-glow-diamond-mangalsutra) they have added 'price + tax' in excel sheet and uploaded the final price in backend. they did't created any tax class

Comment: Let me pull up my test env and get back to you shortly.

Comment: that's fine, other answer worked well for me, thanks...